# How to stop Java from truncating 32bit int to single byte over java.net.Socket ? Or maybe use something else?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

So the code is really as simple as it gets

```
int len = 0x00000097;
Socket sock = new Socket(host, port);
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
out.write(i);
out.flush();
out.write(xml_doc);
out.flush();
```

So the idea is that the host is expecting an xml form but its length before hand. The form is a mere 151 bytes and the host is expecting its length as a 4 byte integer, which I believe is the size of an integer in Java anyway, but no matter which of the stream and print and write varieties and combinations I try, WireShark says on the wire my packet contains one byte, the leading zeroes truncated leaving only <97>. I need a fresh pair of eyes guys ! Please and thanks.

Comment: Please pay more attention to the formatting of your code - it was all on one line before I edited it. Use the preview to see what your question will look like before you post it, and only post it when it looks right.

Comment: I'm surprised that code even compiles - `DataOutputStream` doesn't *have* a `print` method as far as I can tell. Are you *sure* that's your real code? Perhaps you've actually got `write` instead of `print`?

Comment: It's write() sorry, but I've tried wrapping an OutputStreamWriter in a PrintWriter, and also just writing to an OutputStreamWriter, quite a couple other approaches.

Comment: Right, I've edited your post accordingly. *Please* pay attention to this sort of thing before posting.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling [`DataOutput.write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#write-byte:A-) on the `DataOutputStream`, which is documented as:

> Writes to the output stream the eight low-order bits of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.

I suspect you really want [`writeInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt-int-):

> Writes an int to the underlying output stream as four bytes, high byte first. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by 4.

So:

```
out.writeInt(i);
```

Always check the Javadoc of the methods you're using, particularly when they don't behave the way you expect them to.

Comment: I think you just taught me to fish for JavaDocs at first sight of trouble. Thanks again Jon, you're the man.

Comment: @confusedrussian1 You could even consider reading the Javadoc *before* cutting the code ;-)

Comment: Just checking, flush() is supposed to flush all four bytes of the written int() right ? Because wireshark tells me that the first byte <00> indeed is sent with the first flush() and then the other three are appended to the beginning of my xml form as <000097>.

Comment: Not sure why int is a method now... definitely very tired today.

Comment: @confusedrussian1: `flush()` doesn't necessarily flush to the actual network, as far as I'm aware - it just flushes the internal buffers. But so long as you're using TCP *as a stream protocol* (which you should) it shouldn't affect you.

Comment: Am indeed using TCP _hah_

Comment: I'm confident then that its forming the stream correctly... so here comes some server-side troubleshooting. Thanks again Jon. I'm done for the day.